# Generate MontiCore PrettyPrinter

Tags: maven

Is it possible to automatically generate a PrettyPrinter for a [MontiCore](http://monticore.org/) language using the MontiCore Maven plugin? I am using MontiCore 2.2.1 and the corresponding Maven plugin.

Comment: Well I read in the tec report that it is possible to automatically generate a pretty printer. But I did not found a parameter for MC and the Maven Plugin does not seem to have a specific configuration parameter, too. The examples shipped with MontiCore only contain manually written PrettyPrinters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the MontiCore generator for the generation of the pretty printer for your language in addition to the generation of the parser and AST.

The parameter for workflow for the generation of a pretty printer is "ppgen".

You have to extend the configuration of the MontiCore Maven plugin by the following arguments:

```
     <plugin>
          <groupId>de.monticore.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>monticore-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              ...
              <configuration>
                  ...
                  <arguments>
                       <argument>-synthesis ALL generate</argument>
                       <argument>-synthesis ALL ppgen</argument>
                  </arguments>
              </configuration>
              ...
     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the pretty printer for MontiArcAutomaton the following configuration is needed:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.monticore.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>monticore-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
          <arguments>
           <argument>-synthesis grammar prepareCheck</argument> 
           <argument>-synthesis grammar check</argument> 
           <argument>-synthesis grammar generate</argument>  
            <argument>-synthesis dsltool prepareCheck</argument> 
           <argument>-synthesis dsltool check</argument> 
           <argument>-synthesis dsltool generate</argument>  
           <argument>-synthesis grammar ppgen</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
```